# How can I travel with a cancelled passport?

Tags: international, citizenship, air-travel, passport

Say one day my passport is cancelled because I wrote "president s***s" on my Twitter a few years ago. I have only 1 citizenship.

This would probably happen when I'm outside the country (A). I'm trying to spend most of my time outside A as a tourist because I see possibility for major instability these years, which would mean extreme oppression and possibly getting stuck in A for a very long time.

There's a country (B) that's very welcoming in terms of giving citizenships, not quality of life. B gives you a citizenship pretty quickly compared to other ones, though it still takes years (naturalization and citizenship application). The problem is how am I going to go to B without a valid passport?

You might suggest going to B now so I can get the passport ASAP. I'm not doing that because B is dangerous. Living there is going to suck. So it's a last resort kind of thing, that you must endure, so you can have a passport that's not cancelled.

PS.

1. I can't afford to spend hundreds of thousands of dollars to buy a passport. So I'm open to creative ideas as long as it's relatively safe. Maybe there's a way to travel to B without a valid passport?
2. B is in middle of nowhere, so no direct flights usually
3. I can't prove that the government cancelled my passport because I posted some tweets. They're not going to respond to requests from 3rd parties or international organizations. My country is doing a lot worse to BILLIONAIRES and international organizations can't help them.
4. I'm not tortured, fired, threatened by the government. I can't document any kind of proof those international organizations would accept as far as I know.

--

I did some research and there's this thing but it's specific to a handful of countries and you have to be a permanent resident.

> In many cases you can get some kind of international travel document for aliens who can't get a passport from their country of nationality (variously called "alien's passport", "re-entry permit", "certificate of identity", etc.)

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/139426/discussion-on-question-by-user46922-how-can-i-travel-with-a-cancelled-passport).

Answer (score 1):

You can travel to a country with open borders to you, such as within the EU.  You wouldn't be able to stay in a hotel that wants your passport, though.

Any country that has border control will be closed to you unless you can claim refugee status or file for political asylum.  No commercial carrier will take you to another country without a valid passport, since they end up on the hook to take you back home.  If your country has exit controls, you won't be allowed to leave so now you're into illegal egress.

Gaining citizenship in a country that has an open border with yours (or any other) is according to their rules.